# GWT: Where do I place external resources that can be included in my .gwt.xml file?

Tags: gwt

I'm using GWT 2.4.  I want to include some Javascript and CSS files in my main GWT module page.  But I'm having trouble getting them loaded.  In my .gwt.xml file I have

```
<!--  Scripts -->
<script src="js/tabber.js"/>
<script src="js/sortable.js"/>

<!--  Stylesheets -->
<stylesheet src="css/example.css" />
<stylesheet src="css/sortable.css" />
```

The "js" and "css" folders are located in my "war" directory, but evidently that isn't the right place to put them.  Where should they go?  The directories (relative to the root of my project) are

```
gwt-unitCache
src
test
test-classes
war
```

Comment: If you have a question about JSNI please ask it separately - this question is about loading scripts via a `gwt.xml` file.

Answer (score 3):

As far as I remember, these paths are relative to the location of the .gwt.xml file - have you tried placing them there? (i.e. right next to the java packages for that particular module)

**Update**:

"The default public path is the *public* subdirectory underneath where the Module XML File is stored." - http://code.google.com/webtoolkit/doc/latest/DevGuideOrganizingProjects.html#DevGuideModules

Comment: Sadly placing the "js" and "css" folders in the same folder as my .gwt.xml file didn't work.  My .gwt.xml file is in src/com/myco/clearing/productplus folder.  Google keeps talking about a "public" folder?  Is the path I listed public?

Comment: @Dave: Just create a folder called "public" in "src/com/myco/clearing/productplus" and place your js and css there. This way, the js and css folder will be copied to where the compiled GWT javascript will be. I'm not too sure about the details (been a while), but you should be able to find the details here: http://code.google.com/webtoolkit/doc/latest/DevGuideOrganizingProjects.html

Comment: Note: the paths are relative to your built module (`GWT.getModuleBaseURL()`), but you can put absolute URI references too (e.g. to the [Google Libraries API](http://code.google.com/apis/libraries/) or any other CDN)

Comment: See my edit.  Moving stuff into a public folder allows me to reference stuff through a URL, but my JSNI function (included above) is not finding the functions.  Anyone know anything about JSNI?

Comment: Your GWT application runs in the context of an iframe on the page, so the `tabberAutomatic` function isn't visible to it. Access the function using the implicitly defined `$wnd` object: `$wnd.tabberAutomatic(tabberOptions)`.

Comment: Hey Jason, That's absolutely correct.  If you create an answer, I'll accept it.  Thanks, -

Comment: If your project is mavenized you will need to put the public folder on "src/main/resources/your/package/public"

just make sure the path is equal to that of your gwt.xml file.
This works great for maven modules which produce a jar and are intended to be used by another project.